# Receive UDP packet in android

Tags: android, udp

I'm sending UDP packet to android over a wireless network from some other software . how can I receive that in android ? should I write a client in android to get the data?

Comment: There's nothing specific to game dev in this question, and there are similar questions already asked on SO (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102048/how-to-receive-data-using-udp-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [DatagramSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) to receive [DatagramPackets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) via UDP. There's an example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102048/324625).

Comment: but would it get the packet from network ? it does not matter who sends these packets?

Comment: Part of setting up the DatagramSocket is defining what you are listening for... as in, the IP and PORT you expect to be getting packets to and from.

Comment: Generally telling people to google things in your answer body isn't a good idea. Shout at him in the question comments instead :).

Comment: @matarsak how UDP works is **extremely** well documented on the internet - and they explain exactly how the packets arrive (answer: you get every packet that arrives on that NIC on that port - you need to decide if you want the packet). In addition as stevehb originally pointed out searching on Google got him the answer for Android straight away. You will continue to get short answers like this (or none at all) if you ask things that are so easy to find out yourself.